# how to use twitch emote API

Tags: json, api, twitch

Here's a site ( https://twitchemotes.com/apidocs ) that shows an API to get twitch emotes (basically, json describing a set of images belonging to various users).

The API looks simple enough- but they have *no examples of requests*. So, for this example call ( https://twitchemotes.com/api_cache/v3/subscriber.json ), it returns a *huge* amount of data.

**How do I narrow the request to a single channel?**

The website has that example URL, and an example response, but *no info on how to request a single channel*. So, I assume there's some common knowledge I should be drawing from to be able to derive how to do so? Unfortunately, I apparently lack this knowledge. What am I missing?

Comment: You might have better luck using the official API to retrieve emotes: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/chat#get-chat-emoticons-by-set

Comment: that API (v5) is deprecated, and also seems to fail on the same grounds: you can only get the actual URLs if you load a _huge_ amount of data... the new twitch API doesn't seem to even _have_ any emote-related specs...

Comment: No, you can filter by using the `emotesets` query param; it's only large amounts of data if you opt not to use that.  It's deprecated but available until the end of 2018 (15 months from now).  That said, I'm not sure how you get the emoteset-to-channel mapping without querying the full data at least once and creating/saving the mapping yourself.  The new API seems to have very little functionality and I don't see how to use emotes with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get emotes for a specific channel you need to make two requests:

1. http://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/:channel_name/product

You can use this request to resolve the emoticon set IDs for a channel. For most channels under the `plan` array you will have 3 objects that each contain one or more `emoticon_set_ids` arrays. For most channels there will be 3 total. Some channels without 3 tier subscriptions may not have a `plan` array so you can look at `emoticons` for that instead.

(This endpoint is not designed for 3rd party use but it works and probably won't change much. Need to send Kraken client ID.)

2. https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/emoticon_images?emotesets=:emoticon_set_list

(Kraken v3)

Take the 3 emoticon_set_ids values and append them as a comma separated list to the `emotesets` parameter.

I am owner of Twitchemotes and this is basically the process I use to update my index.

Answer (score 1):

This URL can get you all of the emotes and plenty of other information:

> https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/timthetatman/product

where `timthetatman` is the username/login of a channel.

The `emoticons` property has only the first tier of emotes. You can get all of them in the `plans` object:

```
data.plans.reduce((p, n) => p.concat(n.emoticons), []);
```

You can get a direct URL in the emote object, but the preferred URL format would be like this:

> https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/123456/1.0

where `123456` is the emote ID and `1.0` is the scale. Scale can be `1.0`, `2.0`, or `3.0`

```
let id = data.plans[0].emoticons[0].id;
let emoteURL = `https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/${id}/1.0`;
```

Answer (score 0):

api.twitch.tv is gone.

You can also use this API:
https://twitchemotes.com/apidocs

Comment: That API is also gone.